# Android Layout issues

Tags: android, android-layout

In my layout this is not moving the button to the right of the screen. 
What am I missing?
The button is within a linear layout.
But has its own relative layout.

Comment: Can you post the layout file? What is "this?

Comment: check it out this link........ http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/relativelayout-in-android-xml.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this for main.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:text="Right Button" 
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <Button 
            android:text="Button" 
            android:id="@+id/button1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="right">
        </Button>

   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the RelativeLayout android:width to "fill_parent", for the LinearLayout set the android:layout_gravity property to "right"